# MS .mdb realtime sync

Tags: ms-access, synchronization, mirror

We use a shop monitoring software at work that uses a Access database. This has been giving us a few of 3043 disk or network error lately. This error is an incredible pain to troubleshoot especially when it happens rarely and I cannot seem to narrow it down any. Tried a ton of things.

Anyways, I was wondering if I can take the main mdb file which resides on a server, sync it locally to each machine, then point the program to operate off that database. When an update is made or anything is changed, it syncs back to the main mdb file and updates it with the changes. On average there is 6-8 users using the mdb at once and I would really like to avoid losing any data or having corruption issues.

Answer (score 0):

Access seems sensitive to network errors. We have similar problems all the time here. The best solution we've found is to migrate the DB tables to an enterprise level DB (SQL Server, DB2, PostgreSQL, etc...) and use linked tables in Access. This has worked very well for us.

If this isn't an option, you'll probably have to write custom code to do the sync. I know of no way to replicate an Access table, and I know of no way to implement triggers. Linking tables to an Access back-end is not a good idea in the face of network issues.